# How to Multi find aggregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I wanna response DATA is MongoDB aggregate `{category: 'Cadillac'}` Object and `{price: 8000}` Object

two Object can not append or add or assign.

```
[{{ObjectA: 1}, {ObjectA: 2}}, {{ObjectB: data}}]
+
[{{ObjectC: 1}, {ObjectC: 2}}, {{ObjectD: data}}]
```

bad action.

```
car_col.find({category: 'Cadillac'}).sort('date', -1).toArray((err, result) => {
    car_col.find({price: {$le: 8000}}).sort('lastModified').toArray((err, result2) => {
        res.end(result+result2) // bad action
        res.end(Object.assign(result, result2) // bad action
    })
})
```

I ideal is

```
car_col.aggregate([
{
    $match: {category: 'Cadillac'}}, 
    $sort: {date: -1}
},
{
    $match: {price: {$lt: 8000}},
    $sort: {lastModified: -1}
}
```

ideal result is

```
[{{ObjectA: 1}, {ObjectA: 2}}, {{ObjectB: data}}, {{ObjectC: 1}, {ObjectC: 2}}, {{ObjectD: data}}]
```

bad this is not result.

Comment: Explain little further in depth what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was self resolved

```
result3 = result.concat(result2);
```

result

```
[{{ObjectA: 1}, {ObjectA: 2}}, {{ObjectB: data}}, {{ObjectC: 1}, {ObjectC: 2}}, {{ObjectD: data}}]
```